# Why doesn't a null expression in C# convert to an option of None in F# but a literal null does?

Tags: c#-to-f#

I'm creating instances of an F# record type from C#. One of the fields is a `string option`. If I pass an expression that evaluates to `null` for that field, it becomes `Some(null)` in F#. If I pass the `null` keyword it become `None`. This is causing null reference exceptions in the F# code I'm calling from C#.

```ml
type SampleType = {
    Name: string option
}
```

```cs
string nameValue = null;

var sample1 = new SampleType(name: null);
OptionModule.IsNone(sample1.Name); // True because of literal null

var sample2 = new SampleType(name: nameValue);
OptionModule.IsNone(sample2.Name); //  False because Name is Some null in this case.
```

Why isn't the null converted to None in both cases?

Comment: I found the following github issue where this behavior is discussed some detail and the conclusion is that it's by design. It's not likely to be changed because of backwards compatibility concerns. [FSharpOption<T> Implicilty casts to Some(null) instead of None #11565](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/11565)

Comment: Yeah right. So looks like this will stay :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically this happens because an implicit conversion kicks in.

Compare:

```cs
OptionModule.IsNone(new SampleType(null).Name);
```

```cs
OptionModule.IsNone(new SampleType((string)null).Name);
```

So, from the compiler perspective, in the 2nd case it's not going to be a null reference, but a string instance.

That said, the behavior is indeed not intuitive. `IsSome` and `IsNone` could be improved to take this into consideration. You can submit an issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues)!

Comment: I did a similar experiment with mapping from int? to option<int> and DateTime? to option<DateTime>. Those conversions to Some and None are consistent. I was hoping string would be too. I suppose if the C# project has the Nullable option enabled and we used string? that would probably map more smoothly. To get around the issue, I've added the FSharpx ToFSharpOption() extension method to all string values being passed into an F# record constructor and that's been solid.